# Change a paragraph link field title at runtime

Tags: 8, hooks

We have a site with numerous paragraphs, one of which is a Call-to-action, comprised of a title, summary and a link field (machine name: field_link).

The CTA is used so much that to change the word 'Enquire' to 'Inquire' for when we are on a US translation (en-US in url) would require the paragraph been edited manually for every content page that has a us translation would be a monumental task.

As such I've decide to attempt to simply handle this in the paragraph preprocess hook. The original idea was simply to check if we were in a us translation, then check for the word in the field_linl title and change it if needed, as per my snippet below.

```
/* Translation modifier:
   * The call to action paragraph is used on almost all pages and translations
   * doesn't work with paragraphs at all. So we need to detect if we are in a US
   * translation and change out the spelling of certain words.
   */
  if($paragraph_type == 'call_to_action'){

    if(is_us_translation()){
      $cta_link = $paragraph->get('field_link');
      $cta_link->list[0]->values['title'] = 'Inquire';
      $paragraph->set('field_link', $cta_link);

      // $paragraph->values['field_link']['x-default'][0]['title'] = 'Inquire';
    }
  }
```

The commented out line was my other attempt.

My problem though is nothing I have tried seems to manage to change the title of the field. Is there a specific way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook){
  $element = $variables['element'];

  /* Translation modifier:
   * The call to action paragraph is used on almost all pages and translations
   * doesn't work with paragraphs at all. So we need to detect if we are in a US
   * translation and change out the spelling of certain words.
   */
  if(is_us_translation()){
    if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
      if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_link') {
        $str_to_check = strtolower(trim($variables['items'][0]['content']['#title']));

        if(strpos($str_to_check, 'enquire') !== false){
          $variables['items'][0]['content']['#title'] = 'Inquire';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks! $variables['items'][0]['content']['#title'] did the trick.